# How to integrate razorpay with saleor?

Tags: django, razorpay, saleor

I am trying to integrate Razorpay with saleor e-commerce app but could not find anything to start with. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

Saleor at the moment does not support razorpay. You can check out supported payment methods here https://saleor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture/payments.html